# What does x in range(...) == y mean in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just stumbled upon the following line in Python 3.

```
1 in range(2) == True
```

I was expecting this to be `True` since `1 in range(2)` is True and `True == True` is True.

But this outputs `False`. So it does not mean the same as `(1 in range(2)) == True`. Furthermore it does not mean the same as `1 in (range(2) == True)` which raises an error.

Despite years of experience in Python, I am taken off guard. What is going on?

Comment: @chrisz, it's using `in` so if that was the case it'd be a syntax error (`argument of type 'bool' is not iterable`)

Comment: Whoops, you are correct, I misread.

Comment: Evaluation order : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=459269&seqNum=11

Comment: Where exactly did you stumble upon this code?

Comment: A previously deleted question on SO today. Their code was wrong because of that behaviour by the way, but they deleted the question before I could point it out.

Comment: The expression is equivalent to `(1 in range(2)) and (range(2) == True)` of which the second part is false, making the whole condition false.

Comment: I was mislead to think this had a special meaning, but now that you mention it, that makes sense. I admitedly did not realize the in operator could be chained. Thanks.

Comment: @Olivier yeah, it's a little bit counter-intuitive that `in` is a comparison operator. I had to check the actual docs to confirm that suspicion, though.

Comment: Well it makes sense though. It is a binary operator that returns a boolean. I think it would be a design flaw not to treat it as such, especially since you can give it arbitrary behaviour with `__contains__`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to the fact that both operators are comparison operators, so it is being interpreted as operator chaining:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
>   to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

So it is equivalent to:

```
>>> (1 in range(2)) and (range(2) == True)
False
```